# An Atlas for Regular Surfaces Using Normal Polar Coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry

Question: Prove that every regular surface can be covered by an atlas of surface patches with $E=1$ and $F=0$.

Using normal polar coordinates, we know that the fundamental forms of the surface patches are
$$\cal{F}_1=dr^2+Gd\theta^2$$
However, these patches do not cover the point $p$, since the surface patches are defined in the following way: 
$$\sigma(r,\theta)=exp_p((r cos\theta )e_1,(rsin\theta )e_2)$$
and 
$$exp_p(v)=\begin{cases}
p,\ v=0,\\
\gamma(\lvert v \rvert), \ v\neq0 .\\
\end{cases}$$
where $\gamma$ is the geodesic such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma^{\prime}(0)=v$.

I have two ideas to also cover $p$: 
1) The function $\sigma$ is continuous, and $p$ is a limit point of its image (Its domain: $ \{ (r,\theta)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 0<r<\epsilon , 0<\theta 
 <2\pi \})$. Therefore, there exists a continuous extension. But, I am not sure how to prove this if it is even true.

2) We can define these surface patches for every point in the sphere. So, we will have an atlas but it is going to be huge (cardinality is uncountable). This looks very weird to me but still, I could not find a technical issue with this approach. Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $t$ should be $\theta$? There's no need to make a case-by-case definition of the exponential map, and it is smooth (indeed, a diffeomorphism to its image) on a ball centered at $p$. You are correct that you only get a patch when we consider $(0,\epsilon)\times (0,2\pi)$ in this coordinate system. But you can easily recover $p$ and this interval by using a patch centered at (almost any) suitable different point $q$.

Comment: @TedShifrin t should be $\theta$, I will edit it. Thank you. However, that is exactly my question. I do not know (or sure) how to write a proof of this "recover."

Comment: Just pick any $q$ inside this patch (corresponding to some $(r,\theta)$ with $0<\theta<2\pi$). Then $p$ will be inside the $q$ normal coordinate patch as long as you don't choose $e_1$ pointing from $q$ to $p$.